# DIV width according to containing IMG width. Inside text overflow

Tags: html, css, width

I have a `DIV` element which contains `IMG` and some one line text under this image. I would like to make this containing `DIV` the same width as the image width and the overflowing text hidden probably with `overflow:hidden`.

Is there any way how to do that in `HTML` and `CSS` or must I use `JavaScript` in this case ? (**I don't need JS solution**)

**EDIT:** sorry, I should probably mention a few more details. The image's size is unknown because actually there is a lot of those `DIV` elements on the page with different images and in the description under image there are like 4 differently styled lines. I wrote 'ONE LINE' just because only this one line needs to be set with overflow.

Comment: `display: inline-block;`

Comment: @dfsq this will not hide the text, the wrapper div will stretch to display the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do this with CSS but it's not a great solution and I would not recommend it (solution below). You can however, do this very simply with jQuery. Set your container width to be the size of your image on page load and use `nowrap` for whitespace to force the text all on one line (hidden with `overflow:hidden`)

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**JS**

```
var imgWidth = $("img").width();

$(".wrapper").css("width", imgWidth+"px")
```

[**JS EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gbfn2wc5/2/)

To expand upon TreeTree's example of using `position: absolute`. Rather than set the wrapper to relative and use `bottom:0` on the text, you can wrap your content in a container `div` that is set to `relative`. That way you don't have to worry about positioning the text to get it where you want because the div (being a natural block element) will sit below your image to begin with:

```
.wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 60px; //some value to show content
}

.content-wrapper{
   position: relative;
}

.content-wrapper p{
   position: absolute;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[**CSS EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gbfn2wc5/5/)

But between the two I would go with the JS version. The CSS one is a nice concept but a bit hacky. You need to use padding to show the text because positioning it removes it from the flow of the document thus doesn't register a height or width. Depending what you use this for, building your code base around this could create some major issues down the road.

Comment: This does not answer the question; it explicitly asks whether there are non-JavaScript solutions.

Comment: `Is there any way how to do that in HTML and CSS or must I use JavaScript in this case ? ` Yeah i know..the best way to do this is with JS - didnt sound like OP was opposed, just hoping. I posted one for CSS and explained the two. Im confused as to how this doesnt answer the question

Comment: It does not answer the question, which you quoted. An answer to that question is “Yes”, preferably followed by a description of at least one way of doing it in HTML and CSS, or “No.”

Comment: Thanks for the downvote... We should be robots now? No discretion? There is a way to do this, period. AND i provided an alternative CSS version too. I updated my post just to make you happy. If OP has an issue with my answer he/she doesnt have to use it. Plain and simple.

Comment: with little insignificant change your CSS solution works for my updated question. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the text will always be one line you could make it absolute and add a padding to the container.

```
.cont {
    background:orange;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.img {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background:yellow;

}

p {
    position:absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3k3Lqd1j/2/)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it in HTML and CSS, but they are probably all somewhat artificial.

First, note that simply setting a fixed width, same as the image width, on the text, with simple mechanism to hide overflow, would satisfy the question *as asked*. Example:

```css
.ex1 {
  width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class=ex1>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/100/" alt="(a demo image)"><br>
This is  some text under the image. The request is to make the overflowing part hidden.
</div>
```

However, the question was probably intended to ask whether you can do this without hard-coding the image width into CSS settings for the `div`. Such hard-coding might actually be the most practical approach. The reason is that other approaches seem to require more complicated code.

Here is one possible approach: Put the image in a single-cell table and set the text as table caption, placed below the table. (Purists may try to do this using a CSS table.) You need an inner wrapper for the text, since overflow management seems to fail when applied to a `caption` element directly. And you need to let the text overflow vertically; otherwise it extends the table width. For this, set the wrapper’s height to match the height of one line.

```css
.ex2 caption span {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.3;
  height: 1.3em;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing=0 class=ex2>
<caption align=bottom><span>This is  some text under the image. The request is to make the overflowing part hidden.</span></caption>
<tr><td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/100/" alt="(a demo image)">
</table>
```

Comment: interesting approach. thanks. I just used earlier one

Comment: Thank you so much for not using jQuery, and also for using only one containing div (most approaches everywhere use two divs to achieve exactly the same result).

Answer (score 0):

This is the **[same thing](http://jsfiddle.net/gbfn2wc5/4/)** as @jmore009 solution but with using native JavaScript and `id` elements:

```
var imgWidth = document.getElementById("myImg").width;
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.width = imgWidth+"px";
```